# ExecutorService submit vs. execute

Tags: android, executorservice

Am I understanding good that the difference between `submit` and `execute` is like, an `async` and a `sync` call? In second case caller will be stopped until runnable completed?

```
public static ExecutorService serialQueue = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
```

I use `ExecutorService` as serial queue, only one task can run at a time.

Answer (score 3):

`submit()` returns a `Future`, whereas `execute()` doesn't return anything. It appears both are asynchronous, but with `submit()` you can call `future.get()` on the returned `Future` in order to block until the submitted task actually completes. Also, if that task has a result value that you want to get, you can use `submit()` with a `Callable` instead of a `Runnable` and the `future.get()` call will give you that result.

Comment: To add, `execute` is part of the `Executor` interface whereas `submit` is part of the `ExecutorService` interface.  The returned `Future` also allows you to cancel the request where-as `execute` is just going to keep going until it ends on its own.